# In Spring, annotation and xml must be used together?

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

**A class**

```
public class A {

    private String name;

    public A() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**BeanFactory class**

```
public class BeanFactory implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean{

    private A a;

    public BeanFactory(){

    }

    public BeanFactory(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void printAName(){
        System.out.println("Class BeanFactory: beanFactory.printAName -> a.getName() = " + a.getName());

    }       

}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "ApplicationContext.xml");

        BeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getBean("beanFactory",
                BeanFactory.class);

        beanFactory.printAName();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationContext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="beanFactory" class="testSpring.BeanFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="a1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="a1" class="testSpring.A">
        <property name="name" value="I am A!"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

***Result of run***: `Class BeanFactory: beanFactory.printAName -> a.getName() = I am A!`

Like you can see, here I don't use no annotation. But the code works thanks to xml file.

1. So xml doesn't need annotation..? Can I use one or the other?
2. If I would use, in this application, the annotation (`@Autowired` for example) instead of bean xml, it's possible? Can you show me how?
3. Or the annotation must require xml reference?

So.. annotation and xml must be used together? Thanks

Comment: No. You can use annotations, XML or both.

Comment: Ok, If I want use only annotation, how can I do?

Comment: I recommend studying the documentation as well as Googling heavily. It's too broad a question to get a proper answer here (it also depends a lot on what you're doing and using). The term "java config" is used often when talking about annotation based configuration with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You should use annotation configuration, this is the idea

```
@Component
class Bean1 {
    public Bean1() {
        System.out.println(getClass());
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("test")
public class Config {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    }
}
```

For details see Spring docs